# Hibernate EHCache collection "Unable to resolve owner of loading collection"

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache

I am facing an issue with fetching an object from Hibernate with EHcache enabled.
This

This is my hbm.xml snippet of the concerned class

```
<class name="FinanceFacility" table="FIN_FACILITY" discriminator-value="FinanceFacility">
    <cache usage="read-write" region="financeFacilityCache"/>
    <set name="borrowers" access="property" table="FIN_FACILITY_BORROWERS" fetch="subselect" lazy="false" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
        <cache usage="read-write" region="financeFacilityCache"/>
        <key column="FIN_FACILITY_ID"/>
        <element column="GROUP_COMPANY_ID" type="GuidType"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

And this is the API call here which goes via Hibernate.

```
@Override
@Cacheable(cacheName = "assignableFacilityCache") // NOSONAR
public List<FinanceFacility> getAllWhereInventoryCanBeAssigned()
{
    LOG.info("Getting all facilities where inventory can be assigned...");

    List<QueryParam> params = new ArrayList<QueryParam>();

    List<FinanceFacility> facilities = getMultipleEntities("FinanceFacility.findWhereInventoryCanBeAssigned", params);

    // Set the parents
    for (FinanceFacility facility : facilities)
    {
        facility.setParentFacility(getPathTo(facility.getParentRef()));
    }

    LOG.info("getAllFacilities() found " + facilities.size() + " Facility(s)");
    return facilities;
}
```

In normal cases this runs fine. But during some concurrent access I get the below error

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve owner of loading collection [[com.xxx.yyy.internal.model.facilities.FinanceFacility.borrowers#1a21f938e94f4ba2a36a3e973845175e]] for second level caching
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1389) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1317) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at com.xxx.yyy.repository.database.AbstractEntityRepository.getMultipleEntities(AbstractEntityRepository.java:65) ~[classes:na]
```

Any idea what the problem is? Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

Found it

I had to remove fetch="subselect" from the set in hbm mapping to get it working.
I had replaced it with batch-size to keep the optimisation.

Comment: Very odd one this! Looks and feels like a bug to me. To work around it, I changed my query at runtime to a join: `crit.setFetchMode("things", FetchMode.JOIN);`